# Shape of the ThumbSlider

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, slider

I need to change the shape of the `thumbSlider`, I need to obtain a shape different from circular, but I do not know how to do it.

```dart
RotatedBox(
  child: SliderTheme(
    data: SliderThemeData(
      trackHeight: 10.0,
      inactiveTrackColor: backgroundColorTextfield,
      activeTickMarkColor: backgroundColorTextfield,
      thumbColor: homeScreenBackgroundColor,
      
      thumbShape: // here
    ),
    child: Slider.adaptive(
      value: 0,
      onChanged: (value) {},
      max: 20,
      min: 0,
    ),
  ),
  quarterTurns: 9,
),
```

I need to make  this shape.

[image: The shape that I want]

Comment: `somewhat oval shape` is incomplete, can specify by adding image

Comment: sorry, i put an image, thanks

Comment: it is more like scrollBar